# Arango update from 3.3 to 3.7

Tags: permissions, authorization, arangodb

I've been running on Arango 3.3. I booted a new server with Arango 3.7. I've configured both Arangos identically (as much as I can) -- same DBs, data, users, passwords and permissions. But the server code that accesses version 3.3 fails when I point it at 3.7. Connection succeeds on both, returning a jwt. Using that jwt in subsequent queries succeeds on 3.3, but fails on 3.7 with "not authorized to execute this request". I've checked and rechecked user permissions, and as far as I can tell they are the same. Has something changed between 3.3 and 3.7 that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think anything has changed on that level - how did you export and import the data? If you try without auth, does it succeed?

Comment: I used arangodump to export the data from the 3.3 server, and arangorestore to import the data to the 3.7 server. I can log in to the 3.3 server using the web interface, and I can connect to the 3.3 server with the _open/auth api , and it returns a JWT. I use that JWT to submit a query just fine. But when I repeat this process with the 3.7 server (_open/auth with the same credentials, get a JWT, use that JWT to submit the same query), I get "not authorized to execute this request". Turning off authentication on the 3.7 server doesn't help. Queries to 3.7 from the web interface work fine.

Comment: It sounds to me like there is an issue with users and database permissions, but based on your procedure, I'm not sure why this would be happening. There is unfortunately low user participation on Stackoverflow, I would suggest perhaps asking your question on the [Arango Slack](https://slack.arangodb.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, will do

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help!